# App Engine ignoring XMPP NORMAL type messages

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

the [XMPP Java API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/) states that both `normal` and `chat` message types are supported and received via the same path, i.e. `/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/`.

It appears that `normal` messages are being ignored either by the XMPP server or by App Engine. Using Smack from my test client, I simply interchange the statements:

```
Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
```

by

```
Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.normal);
```

the second message never being received at my app engine application.

Anyone else has experience this issue?

Answer (score -1):

It is happening because App Engine receiving a XMPP message of an unsupported type, if it is the case then it wouldn't handle that request. So please check your message type which you are you are trying to send. Go through the link of the document for better understanding of XMPP [1].

[1] **XMPP:** https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/#Java_Handling_incoming_calls